# Prove that ${x^2+y^2=z^n}$ has a solution in $\mathbb{N}$ for all $n$ in $\mathbb{N}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

I am solving it by stating that $$x^2 +y^2 =c^2$$
represents a circle. And when $$c^2=z^n$$ then , it represents a system of concentric circles with radius varying as $z$ varies or $n$ varies.
So, for all $n$ in $\mathbb{N}$, $z^n$ represents the radius of the circle. Hence, $x^2 + y^2 =z^n$ has solution in $\mathbb{N}$.

This proof is not formal. It may even be wrong. I really need to know how to prove it formally using theorems from Number Theory. 
Please help me! Thank you! :)

Comment: You magically jump from "$z^n$ is the radius of a circle" (the radius is in fact $\sqrt{z^n}$) to "Hence, $x^2+y^2 = z^n$ has a solution".  That's not informal, that's just stating what you want to prove with no argument.  Since when does a circle automatically have integer coordinates?  (Hint: when $z=3$ it doesn't.)

Comment: I said it may be wrong! :P

Comment: Possible duplicate of [$x^2+y^2=z^n$: Find solutions without Pythagoras!](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2072371/x2y2-zn-find-solutions-without-pythagoras)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Clearly
$$
5^2+10^2=5^3,
$$
and hence
$$
(5^{k+1})^2+(10\cdot 5^k)^2=5^{2k+3}.
$$
Thus, for every $n$ odd your claim holds.

Then 
$$
3^2+4^2=5^2,
$$
implies that
$$
(3\cdot 5^k)^2+(4\cdot 5^k)^2=5^{2+2k},
$$
Thus, for every $n$ even your claim holds.

Answer (score 1):

Note

$$(2^k)^2+(2^k)^2=2\times 2^{2k}=2^{2k+1}$$

So there is a solution for ever odd n.

Answer (score 1):

By Lagrange's identity:
$$ (a^2+b^2)(c^2+d^2)=(ac+bd)^2+(ad-bc)^2 $$
it follows that the numbers that can be represented as a sum of two squares form a semigroup.

Since every prime of the form $4k+1$ can be represented as a sum of two squares, a sufficient condition for
$$x^2+y^2 = z^n $$
to be solvable over the integers is that $z$ has no prime divisors of the form $4k+3$.