# $x^2+y^2=z^n$: Find solutions without Pythagoras!

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations, pythagorean-triples

I was presented with the following problem:

> Prove that there exist solutions to $x^2+y^2=z^n$ for all $n$, with $x,y,z, n \in \mathbb{N}$

I showed that by taking any Pythagorean triple $x^2+y^2=z^2$ and multiplying by $z^{2(n-1)}$ we get $(z^{n-1}x)^2+(z^{n-1}y)^2=(z^2)^n$, which allows me to generate solutions easily for any value of $n$. I managed to find several similar questions on this site, such as [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/334839/variation-of-pythagorean-triplets-x2y2-z3) concerning the specific case $n=3$. I notice that all of these questions take a similar approach and start with a Pythagorean triple and use it to generate general solutions.

Is there a way to prove the statement (or better yet provide solutions to the equation) without first relying on Pythagoras?

Comment: N is a natural number too; I just edited the question to reflect this.

Comment: Since $n \in \mathbb{N}$, infinitely many solutions may be generated when $n=1$.

Comment: the issue is not correct. I must say that if any decisions do not have such a form.  $z=p^2+s^2$

Comment: I suppose $x,y,z$ most not be zero, otherwise it's trivial

Comment: There are infinitely many primitive solutions (that is $\gcd(x,y,z)=1$).  Take two relatively prime integers $p$ and $q$ such that $p-q$ is odd.  Choose $x$ and $y$ such that $$x+yi=(p+qi)^n.$$  Then, $$x^2+y^2=z^n,$$ where $$z=p^2+q^2.$$  By the choices of $p$ and $q$, $\gcd(x,y,z)=1$.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The solution $(x,y,z)=(0,1,1)$ works for all $n$.

---

If you don't want to allow $0$, then let $x,y\in\Bbb{N}$ be such that
$$x+yi=(1+2i)^n.$$
Then
$$5^n=((1+2i)(1-2i))^n=(1+2i)^n(1-2i)^n=(x+yi)(x-yi)=x^2+y^2.$$

---

Alternatively, if $n$ is odd let $m:=\frac{n-1}{2}$ so that
$$(2^m)^2+(2^m)^2=2^n.$$

---

Finally, less constructively, a theorem of Gauss tells us that if an integer is not divisible by any prime congruent to $3$ modulo $4$, then it is a sum of two squares. Hence solutions exist for any $n$.

Comment: Question says x,y,z belong to N. 0 does not belong to N.

Comment: I've rarely encountered an instance of $\Bbb{N}$ not containing $0$ outside this forum, but as it does make the question somewhat less trivial I'll updat my answer.

Comment: The standard ISO 80000-2 (International Organisation for Standardization) includes $0 \in \mathbb{N}$. However, other definitions suggest that $1$ is the smallest element of $\mathbb{N}$

Comment: @Servaes. In this forum the consensus is that $\mathbb N$ is the positive integers, which is something I have reluctantly accepted.

Comment: In that case, I suggest you use $\mathbb{Z}^+$ instead. It is significantly less ambiguous.

Comment: For me, $0\in\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: @inéquation I have friends who work at the Kahn Academy. They are math tutors, and they teach that $0\notin \mathbb{N}$ and that it is instead a *whole number*. I can't disagree, can I? If it is stated by the book...

Comment: @DanielWainfleet yes, I have been taught that $\mathbb{N} = \mathbb{Z}^+$.

Comment: @user477343 I don't understand why can't you disagree. $\mathbb{N}=\{0,1,2,\ldots\}$, $\mathbb{Z}_+=\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{N}^*=\{1,2,3,\ldots\}=\mathbb{Z}_+^*$.

Comment: @user477343. The meaning of the symbol $\Bbb N$ varies  by country, by era, and by author. On this site the prevailing use is that $\Bbb N=\Bbb Z^+,$  which I have reluctantly acceded to.

Comment: @inéquation $0$ is not a positive integer, because $0=-0$. Thus, $0\notin \mathbb{Z}^+$.... but thinking about it more, $0 \not< 0$ either so it really all depends, and in one way or another, I guess you cpould be right.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet thank you for that note. I believe I had a very narrow-minded perspective on things.

Comment: @user477343 I use the term positive in the bourbaki sense $\geq 0$. A natural number is a number that is used to count things: I have 1 cellphone, 2 bikes, 0 airplanes. In this sense, $0$ is just as natural as $1$ or $2$; it is the number of elements in a finite set (if there is no bijection between a set and any of its subset, we call it finite).

Comment: @inéquation so would then the negative integers be $\leqslant 0$? I guess not if you separate the definition of the natural numbers from the positive integers, i.e. $\mathbb{N}\neq\mathbb{Z}^+$. I guess I could just say that $0\in \mathbb{N}$ and $0\notin\mathbb{N}^+$, but now $\mathbb{N}=\mathbb{W}$ which is the set of whole numbers... How I look at it is that when kids learn to count, they start from $1$ and not $0$. But sometimes they do. Like starting a week from Sunday rather than Monday. But for me personally, I treat the natural numbers as counting numbers starting from $1$ and not $0$.

Comment: @inéquation briefly, there's no right or wrong definition as it's up to personal interpretation, I guess. Here I use $\mathbb{N}^+$ instead of $\mathbb{N}^*$.

Comment: @user477343 Definitions are not right are wrong. Just be clear about which definition you are using whenever there might be confusion, as with $\Bbb{N}$.

Comment: @Servaes ok. It's just that different books say different things. Like the use of my set notation was frowned upon in one of my questions I posted, but I was taught that it was completely fine. I will definitely be clear about things like this next time. Thanks :)

Comment: @user477343 Yes negative means $\leq 0$. What do you mean by a whole number? The notation $\mathbb{N}$ is almost universal in many languages whereas $\mathbb{W}$ is far from it (it's the first time I see it).

Comment: @inéquation I was taught that $\mathbb{N}=\{1,2,3,\ldots\}$ and $\mathbb{W}=\mathbb{N}\cup\{0\}$. So $0\notin\mathbb{N}$ but $0\in\mathbb{W}$. Though I would definitely agree that $\mathbb{N}$ is more universal.

Comment: @user477343 The concept of "whole number" is only limited to english. In french for example, "whole number" and "integer" mean the same thing: "nombre entier". I use $\mathbb{N}$ in the Bourbali sense ($0\in\mathbb{N}$). Other users on this site don't.

Comment: @inéquation Apologies, I didn't realise. Do you think there should be a universal consensus on what definitions should be, such as for $\mathbb{N}$, in order to avoid confusion?

Comment: @user477343 I think there should be a universal consensus on $\mathbb{N}$, on the decimal separator, on the open interval notation ($]a,b,[$ or $(a,b)$ like an ordered pair), positive ($\geq 0$ or $>0$), ... on everything. [Some people](http://slideplayer.com/slide/6221744/20/images/2/Getting+to+Know+Metrics+%E2%80%93+Unit+1.jpg) don't even use the metric system!

Comment: @inéquation or even $f(x)|_b^a$ or $[f(x)]_b^a$ or $f(x)]_b^a$. And then we got $n(X)$ or $\#X$ or $|X|$ or $\text{card}(X)$. But imho, $]a,b[$ just looks ugly. Like using $\ni$ for "such that". Decimal seperator is a big one, though :)

Comment: @user477343 I know it's a matter of opinion but let me explain why I prefer $]a,b[$. First the open interval $(a,b)$ and the ordered pair $(a,b)$ shouldnt have the same notation so $x\in (a,b)$ is ambiguous. Second, it helps in geometry. $(AB)$ is a line and $[AB]$ is a line segment. How do you denote the segment $[AB]$ without its endpoints? (my ans: $]AB[$). How do you denote the half line starting at $A$ passing by $B$ and extending indefinitely? ($[AB)$) What if we remove $A$ from this half-line? ( $]AB)$ ).

Comment: @inéquation definitely a great point. But (not intending on an argument, but just a civil discussion) is there something better to write than $]...[$? An alternative other than $(...)$? I also denote $AB$ as a line instead of $(AB)$, which would be my notation for a line without its endpoints.

Comment: @inéquation I would also probably not use math to notate what I mean, and just write it word for word. e.g. we can write something like $$\sum_{p\text{ prime}} p$$ without getting into trouble ... But then there is also Apostol's notation, $$\sum_p ' p$$

Comment: $(AB)$ is the line, $AB$ is the distance between $A$ and $B$. Of course we can use words instead of symbols but geometry proofs will double in length this way. I explained why I prefer these notation, no need to push any notation. Just use whichever notation you want.

Answer (score 3):

I interpret your question as follows: for any positive integer $n$, there exists a positive integer $z$ such that $z^n$ is a sum of two squares (of integers). But Gauss' theorem on sums of two squares - based on the decomposition of primes in the Gaussian integers - states that a positive integer $z$ is a sum of two squares iff for any prime $p\equiv 3 \bmod 4$, the exponent $v_p(z)$ such that $p^{v_p(z)}$ divides exactly $z$ (this could be $0$) is even . Since $v_p(z^n)=nv_p(z)$, we conclude that : - if $n$ is even, any $z$ will do  -if $n$ is odd, $z$ will do iff $z$ itself is a sum of two squares .