# Modified pythagoras' theorem.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Given the equation: $$x^2 + y^2 = z^n $$
Prove that there are solutions in $\mathbb N$. Provided that $n\in\mathbb N.$

Please don't give me the full answer, rather a way to attack the problem, I have no idea how to tackle this proof.

Comment: Some people include $0$ in $\mathbb N$, others do not. Is zero a natural number?

Comment: And we have no idea what answer to give because we don't have any context.  I can think of a theorem that  solves your problem, but you may not be that far into the book yet.

Comment: Do you know about the Gaussian integers, $\mathbb Z[i]$?

Comment: If you want to prove the existence of a solution, can't you just show a solution that works? e.g. $$3^2+4^2=5^2$$ where $z=5$ and $n=2$

Comment: I think the point is to show that is a solution for each $n$. @Jazzachi

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Ah okay.

Comment: @B.Goddard It's in the second chapter of "challenge and thrill of pre college mathematics" called "the arithmetic of integers"

Comment: Also a duplicate of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1248042/prove-that-x2y2-zn-has-a-solution-in-mathbbn-for-all-n-in-mathb

Comment: I just  streched my arm to my book shelf and took the book *challenge and thrill of pre college mathematics*. But sadly, it was a duplicate.